# PFLogInViewController with multiple Twitter accounts

Tags: ios, twitter, parse-platform

Is there a way to use the PFLogInViewController when there are multiple Twitter accounts on defined on the device?

Currently the login only works when I have a single account but after adding another one the login simply hangs - just showing the loading animation without giving any notification to the user / console.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem with only being able to login to one Facebook account. After a lot of research I couldn't find a way! Had to use multiple simulators in xcode to test with users. I think the reason was because it automatically looks in the iphone's Twitter/Facebook account. I believe if you change it in your iphone settings you can use multiple accounts.